# In Nvd3 multiBarChart, how to to control the spacing between the bars for displaying discrete data?

Tags: javascript

I am unable to control the spacing between the bars for displaying discrete data.

`chart.showlabels(true)` gives an error.

`chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Target Record')` does not display yaxis label.